# MySQL select UTF-8 string with '=' but not with 'LIKE'

Tags: mysql, unicode, utf-8, collation

I have a table with some words that come from medieval books and have some accented letters that doesn't exists anymore in modern latin1 alphabet. I can represent these letters easily with UTF-8 combining characters. For example, to create a "J" with a tilde, I use the UTF-8 sequence \u004A+\u0303 and the J becomes accented with a tilde.

The table uses utf8 encoding and the field collation is utf8_unicode_ci.

My problem is the following: If I try to select the entire string, I receive the correct answer. If I try to select using 'LIKE', I receive the wrong answer.

For example:

```
mysql> select word, hex(word) from oldword where word = 'hua';
+--------+--------------+
| word   | hex(word)    |
+--------+--------------+
| hũa    | 6875CC8361   |
| huã    | 6875C3A3     |
| hua    | 687561       |
| hũã    | 6875CC83C3A3 |
+--------+--------------+
4 rows in set (0,04 sec)

mysql> select word, hex(word) from oldword where word like 'hua';
+-------+------------+
| word  | hex(word)  |
+-------+------------+
| huã   | 6875C3A3   |
| hua   | 687561     |
+-------+------------+
2 rows in set (0,04 sec)
```

I don't want to search only the entire word. I want to search words that start with some substring. Eventually the searched word is the entire word.

How could I select the partial string using like and match all the strings?

I tried to create a custom collation using [this information](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/adding-collation-unicode-uca.html), but the server became unstable and only after a lot of trials and errors I was able to revert to the utf8_unicode_ci collation again and the server returned to normal condition.

**EDIT:** There's a problem with this site and some characters don't display correctly. Please see the results on these pastebins:

http://pastebin.com/mckJTLFX

http://pastebin.com/WP87QvgB

Comment: what happens if you try:  like 'hua%'

Comment: I edited the question because the Stackoverflow removed some accented chars. Please see that pastebin. Answering your question, it is here on this pastebin http://pastebin.com/P6cZVHYE

Comment: Please report at http://bugs.mysql.com

Comment: @RickJames do you think this is a bug? I thought it was at first, but now I think it's not a bug, as described on my answer and in MarcusAdams' answer.

Comment: The "bug" may be resolved by a note in the `LIKE` part of the manual, explaining how case folding is honored, but combining characters are treated as separate.  It both of us; so I claim it deserves some action.

Comment: @RickJames Thanks. Bug reported as you suggested  http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=76226

Comment: @RickJames the discussion is still going on there... Due to my fault I didn't see a comment asking for more info and it was closed. Now it returned to discussion. https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=76226

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After seeing Marcus Adams' answer I realized that the REPLACE function could be the solution for this problem, although he didn't mentioned this function.

As I have only two different combining characters (acute and tilde), combined with other ASCII characters, for example j with tilde, j with acute, m with tilde, s with tilde, and so on. I just have to replace these two characters when using LIKE.

After searching the manual, I learned about the UNHEX function that helped me to properly represent the combining characters alone in the query to remove them.

The combining tilde is represented by `CC83` in HEX code and the acute is represented by `CC81` in HEX.

So, the query that solves my problem is this one.

```
SELECT word, REPLACE(REPLACE(word, UNHEX("CC83"), ""), UNHEX("CC81"), "")
FROM oldword WHERE REPLACE(REPLACE(word, UNHEX("CC83"), ""), UNHEX("CC81"), "") 
LIKE 'hua%';`
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `LIKE` performs the comparison character-by-character and when using the "combining tilda", it literally is two characters, though it displays as one (assuming your client supports displaying it as such).

There will never be a case where comparing e.g. `hu~a` to `hua` character-by-character will match because it's comparing `~` with `a` for the third character.

Collations (and coercions) work in your favor and handle such things when comparing the string as a whole, but not when comparing character-by-character.

Even if you considered using `SUBSTRING()` as a hack instead of using `LIKE` with a wildcard `%` to perform a prefix search, consider the following:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING('hũa', 1, 3) = 'hua'
-> 0
SELECT SUBSTRING('hũa', 1, 4) = 'hua'
-> 1
```

You kind of have to know the length you're going for or brute force it like this:

```
SELECT * FROM oldword
WHERE SUBSTRING(word, 1, 3) = 'hua'
   OR SUBSTRING(word, 1, 4) = 'hua'
   OR SUBSTRING(word, 1, 5) = 'hua'
   OR SUBSTRING(word, 1, 6) = 'hua'
```

Comment: It occurred to me now another possible solution. I have only three or four combining characters that are combined with several letters. What if I use the replace function to remove these combining characters when using LIKE? For example: `SELECT word from oldword WHERE REPLACE(word, "˜", "") LIKE 'hua%'`;

Answer (score 1):

According to [*this*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/utf8_collations.html):

`ũ` collates equal to plain `U` in all utf8 collations on 5.6.

`j́` collates equal to plain `J` in most collations; exceptions:

- `utf8_general*ci` because it is actually `j` plus an accent.  And the "general" collations only look at one *character* (as distinguished from *byte*) at a time.  Most collations take into consideration multiple characters, such as `ch` or `ll` in Spanish or `ss` in German.
- `utf8_roman_ci`, which is quite an oddball.  `j́=i=j`

(`LIKE` does not exactly follow the regular rules of collation.  I am not versed on the details, but I think that `J` is represented as 2 characters causes it to work differently in `LIKE` than in `WHERE` or `ORDER BY`.  Furthermore, I don't know whether `REPLACE()` collates like `LIKE` or the other places.)

Answer (score -1):

You can use the % symbol like a wildcard character. For example this:

```
SELECT word
FROM myTable
WHERE word LIKE 'hua%';
```

This will pull all records that start with hua and have 0+ characters following it. Here is an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/93139/1) example.

Comment: The problem is that between "u" and "a" there's a combining tilde.

Comment: @javsmo any chance you can do a select all, or show some of the rows that *aren't* being included so I can recreate it with SQL Fiddle?

Comment: the first select on the pastebin has all rows that matches 'hua' with and without  accents. The char "ũ" uses two chars, an "u" and a combining tilde. This example uses a combination that can be represented also by one char \u0169, but there are other cases, for example a "J" with tilde that only can be represented with \u004a+\u0303

Comment: The point has been missed here, the issue is with the "special" character. not about simple ASCII strings.