# SELECT * FROM varer WHERE varenavn like '%å%';

Tags: mysql

I have an article register containing scandinavian characters. When I search for æø in the articles it works fine, but when searching for å I also get a.

Is there a way to get only å?

```
SELECT * FROM varer WHERE varenavn like '%å%';
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43626573/duplicate-unicode-entry-error-on-the-unique-column-mysql

You can check this answer.

Comment: This pages will be helpfull: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28463156/mysql-select-utf-8-string-with-but-not-with-like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6552950/mysql-matching-unicode-characters-with-ascii-version

Comment: Thanks! i hva been using utf_8 general, and changing til utf_8 bin now..